# Asymptotic Complexity of Small Functions

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory, asymptotic-complexity

I am currently learning Java and basic algorithms by myself. I am struggling with the runtime complexity of loops and some recursive functions in terms of `n` (i.e `O(n^2)`). For example, for the following program:

```
public static void p(int n) {
    if (n == 0) return;  //n times??
    int s = 0; // n times?
    for (int k = 1; k <= Math.min(100, n); k = k + 1) {
    //'k = 1' is n times, 'k<=mathmin' I am not sure on this one
    //'k = k+1' is n*n or n*100?
        s = s + 10;  //n*n or n*100 times??
    }
    p(n - 1);  //n-1 times?
    //and also what about the overall asymptotic complexity?
    //is it just simply adding together all the above number of times?
}
```

I commented my interpretations of the runtime of each step in the program but I am not sure whether I am on the right track or not. could someone help me please??

Comment: It is O(n) because the loop inside the procedure does a min with a constant value, so it can be regarded as constant time.

Comment: @maraca I don't quite get you. Can you explain more about the procedure and how O(n) comes from please?

Comment: Big O notation is usually assumed to mean as inputs get arbitrarily large so in this case the inner loop is bound to a constant.. so O(n)

Comment: @LucasKot-Zaniewski Is it because Math.min(100,n) so the loop can be executed for 100 times at most, which means it is bound to a constant?

Comment: @Dan2038 correct!

Comment: think about it.. what if you said "well it's n^2 for all n less than 100". Although you'd technically be correct it would lead to an inconsistency because what if your inner loop always looped to a hundred? Then it would technically be O(n) *always*. Yet clearly this algo is shorter because it doesn't loop to 100 in the range n<100! That's why you should assume arbitrarily large number as a barometer.

Comment: @LucasKot-Zaniewski Thanks this is helpful! If I look into another case:                
`int sum = 0;
 for (int h = 1; h <= n; h = h+1) {
     for (int k = Math.min(10000, h); 0<k; k = k+1) {
         sum = sum + 10;
     }
 }
 sum = sum + 9999`
What would be the asymptotic complexity for this program with a double loop in it?

Comment: this one would go for infinity as k will always be greater than 0 so hard to say

Comment: @LucasKot-Zaniewski Oh sorry, in the inner loop, it should be `k = k-1`

Comment: it's the same concept as before just looping in a diff direction. You are binding the inner loop to a fixed ceiling so as n gets arbitrarily large the inner loop has a fixed size

Comment: @LucasKot-Zaniewski So is it a total of (1+10000*n+1) steps, which leads to a `O(n)`? And a last question, if we want to get the tightest asymptotic complexity, do we need to analyze two different situations where 1) n > 10000; 2) n<10000 ??

Comment: well what do you think?

Comment: @LucasKot-Zaniewski Still O(n) right?

Comment: not sure what tightest asymptotic complexity is but whats the order of the function of iterations in terms of input when n is less than 10000? That's how I'd look at it. Just beware that this is not the big O value of the actual function.

Comment: I think the key is the word `asymptotic`. It means you have to look what you get when `n` goes towards *infinity* and therefore any loop bound by min(c, n) no matter how large constant c is will be constant time. @Dan2038

Comment: @LucasKot-Zaniewski  If I replace 10000 with 10, it feels like we could consider the inner loop has only 10 iterations at most, which can result in the O(n). But since 10000 is a relatively large number, I am not sure whether we can conclude the inner loop has O(1) (constant time) or not.

Comment: It can be a bit confusing. Let's say we put in `Integer.MAX_VALUE` as constant. So the min doesn't change anything and suddenly we have O(1) instead of O(n). But doing a min(max, n) is not the same as just putting n there, because if you would extend the function to long (without changing the constant) then they would return different results for large numbers. So although they both would return the same result for the range they are defined in, they are actually not the same function and have different asymptotic complexity.

Comment: @Dan2038 why is 10000 a relatively large number while 10 is not? That seems like an unfounded statement without context. You should look at what the complexity converges to when you get larger than 10000 for big O notation because arbitrarily large happens to be *greater* than 10000 in this case.